# Dúvida na recuperação do valor da callback no NodeJs

Tags: javascript, node.js

Pessoal estou iniciando no node.js execução de function e gostaria de saber como retornar um campo do db e passar para uma variável, geralmente uso uma callback, por exemplo:

```js
Conect.query('select nome from pessoa where id=1', function(erros, data){
Console.log(data)
}
```

Mas gostaria de retornar em uma variável externa essa data por exemplo:

```js
Var banco = Conect.query('select nome from pessoa whre id=1')
```

Porém quando faço isso ele retornar parâmetros da conexão e da query que está sendo executada, eu consigo retornar o valor desse campo em uma Promisse de repente ou algo do tipo?

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript não funciona assim, todas as operações de io (entrada e saída) em JavaScript são feitas de forma assíncrona, ou seja, a sua thread não espera a resolução dessas operações para continuar executando as próximas linhas de código, então geralmente é necessário passar uma função de callback para ser executada quando a operação de io terminar.

... Ou ao menos era assim que funcionava até 2017. Utilizando o modificador `async` na sua função, você pode interromper a execução da função até receber a resposta de uma `Promise`. O que você precisa fazer é encapsular esse método numa Promise:

```
// Módulo "util" já é incluido no NodeJS
var util = require('util')
var query = util.promisify(Conect.query)
```

E agora você pode esperar por essa resposta dentro de uma função `async` com o operador `await`:

```
async function minhaFuncao() {
    var data = await query('select nome from pessoa whre id=1')
}
```

Note que apesar da sua função esperar pela resolução da `Promise`, a sua thread não espera. Informe-se de como `Promise`, `async` e `await` funcionam, e quando é uma boa ideia utiliza-los.